# Get the pixels of the image with emgu cv

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv, emgucv

For getting the pixels in the OpenCV I use this code:

```
for( int y=0; y<image->height; y++ ) {
            uchar* ptr = (uchar*) (image->imageData + y * image->widthStep);
            for( int x=0; x<image->width; x++ ) {
                 byteArray[y*image->widthStep+3*x] =  ptr[3*x];     
                  byteArray[y*image->widthStep+3*x+1] =  ptr[3*x+1];   
                   byteArray[y*image->widthStep+3*x+2] =  ptr[3*x+2]; 

            }
    }
```

But I can't use code like this in EmguCV:

```
for( int y=0; y<rgb32Image->MIplImage.height; y++ ) {
 unsigned char* ptr = (unsigned char*) (rgb32Image->MIplImage.imageData + y*rgb32Image->MIplImage.widthStep); 
 //error C2678: binary '+' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'System::IntPtr' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

             for( int x=0; x<rgb32Image->MIplImage.widthStep; x++ ) {
                b[y*rgb32Image->MIplImage.widthStep+3*x] = ptr[3*x];     
                b[y*rgb32Image->MIplImage.widthStep+3*x+1] = ptr[3*x+1];  
                b[y*rgb32Image->MIplImage.widthStep+3*x+2] = ptr[3*x+2]; 

                }

        }
```

**What should I use instead MIplImage.imageData for getting pixels of the image in Emgu CV?**

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Emgu are you using? I usually use Emgu's Image class

You can get a byte[] from 
    Image.Bytes

Documentation here:
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/24efb2ef-4b77-68e5-c8cf-1395430b3666.htm